# CMake: How to check if some flag has been defined

Tags: c++, cmake

I've got something like this in the CMakeLists file:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-g -Wextra -DFLAG1=A")
```

Later in the file, I need to check if `FLAG1` has been defined. Is it possible to do something like this?

```
IF(${FLAG1} EQUAL A)
    #Do something
ELSE()
    #Do something else
ENDIF()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can do

```
set(FLAG1 A)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-g -Wextra -DFLAG1=${FLAG1}")
...
if(${FLAG1} STREQUAL A)
...
```